# Auto Authorize SSH Auth Requests on Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I'm doing something in my build to get this output in my travis tests. It hangs since my test cannot accept or decline, and the test fails:

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.154)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1blah.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I had a similar problem with github.com but I changed to read only urls. Instead of dealing with this problem for every x.com that hosts a git repo, is there a way to have travis just auto authorize any auth request via ssh that is made? I can do this locally via something like this: http://debuggable.com/posts/disable-strict-host-checking-for-git-clone:49896ff3-0ac0-4263-9703-1eae4834cda3 is it possible to set something like that up on Travis?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, think i figured it out. One option is to add those lines to your ~/.ssh/config in a before_script like this:

```
before_script:
  - echo -e "Host heroku.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: This is indeed the right way to do it. Any chance you could accept your own answer (that way the question doesn't appear as "unanswered" anymore)?

Comment: I added the above to both my ~/.ssh/config and to my .travis.yml file and neither works, what am I missing?

Comment: This didn't work for me either; I used @Intentss approach and it worked great.

Answer (score 16):

There is new `travis` built-in setting for this

Just add it to your config

```
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts:
  - git.example.com
```

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ssh-known-hosts/

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this error with travis-ci it may be because one of the gems in your gems file is using github @git

For example this:

```
gem 'pi_piper', :git => 'git@github.com:bguest/pi_piper.git', :branch => 'stub-driver'
```

Needs to look like this

```
gem 'pi_piper', :git => 'https://github.com/bguest/pi_piper.git', :branch => 'stub-driver'
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option, rather than reducing your security as in the accepted answer, is to let travis know that it is in fact a trusted host.

Their docs go over this:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ssh-known-hosts/#mitigations-and-workarounds

Basically, grab the public key from the server, and add it to your known_hosts file on travis, in your .travis.yml:

```
install:
  - echo 'full_server_public_key_goes_here' >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```